# torchrun fails trying to train a model

Tags: ubuntu, pytorch, llama

I'm trying to follow the steps in the ReadMe at https://github.com/facebookresearch/codellama?tab=readme-ov-file .

I downloaded the 7b-Python model and cloned the repo .

When I run this command

```
torchrun --nproc_per_node 1 example_completion.py --ckpt_dir CodeLlama-7b-Python/ --tokenizer_path CodeLlama-7b-Python/tokenizer.model --max_seq_len 128 --max_batch_size 4
```

I get this error:

```
> initializing model parallel with size 1
> initializing ddp with size 1
> initializing pipeline with size 1
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/__init__.py:690: UserWarning: torch.set_default_tensor_type() is deprecated as of PyTorch 2.1, please use torch.set_default_dtype() and torch.set_default_device() as alternatives. (Triggered internally at ../torch/csrc/tensor/python_tensor.cpp:451.)
  _C._set_default_tensor_type(t)
[2024-01-31 12:53:38,520] torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api: [ERROR] failed (exitcode: -9) local_rank: 0 (pid: 4662) of binary: /usr/bin/python3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/torchrun", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/errors/__init__.py", line 347, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 812, in main
    run(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 803, in run
    elastic_launch(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 135, in __call__
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 268, in launch_agent
    raise ChildFailedError(
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.ChildFailedError:
=====================================================
example_completion.py FAILED
-----------------------------------------------------
Failures:
  <NO_OTHER_FAILURES>
-----------------------------------------------------
Root Cause (first observed failure):
[0]:
  time      : 2024-01-31_12:53:38
  host      : 2dba1d14e16b
  rank      : 0 (local_rank: 0)
  exitcode  : -9 (pid: 4662)
  error_file: <N/A>
  traceback : Signal 9 (SIGKILL) received by PID 4662
=====================================================
```